# search text in a website programmatically

Tags: android

i want my app to search a specific website(from an url) for a specific text and give me the 3 chars after that text or to search for a pattern with a placeholder and give me the first matching string. Is that possible? There is no need to display the website.

Comment: **Yes, it's possible.** (This is technically the answer to the question you asked.) Beyond that, your question is much too broad, and you'll need to do a little bit of the legwork yourself. There are plenty of examples for this, and even more similar questions here on SO.

Comment: you have to use html parsing. jsoup lib is what you need. read about it. do it on your side. and ask question if you have any problem. this question has a long answer friend.

Comment: This sort of thing is easy using Python, PHP, Ruby, even javascript, its an unbelievable nightmare using VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you download the page using something like HTTPUrlConnection, you can use a regex with your search term

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("specific text(\w\w\w)");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(site_text);
 boolean b = m.matches();
```

The three \w will be captured in a group for you to use if there's a match.